# How to avoid converting new_line characters to vertical_tab characters when pasting code into Pycharm editor copied from PowerPoint?

Tags: pycharm, copy, powerpoint, editor, paste

When I try to paste code into PyCharm editor coped from PowerPoint slides, I see vertical tabs instead of new lines as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eST3l.png)
This always happens when I (rich) copy code from PyCharm editor into PowerPoint slide and copy the code from the slide into PyCharm editor again.

It does not happen If the rich copy mode is not used when the code was copied from PyCharm and pasted into PowerPoint slides.
However I want to use the rich copy mode when I paste code to PowerPoint because it looks better than plain texts.
How to avoid this happening?